# Why is identical mvn build on different agents producing different results?

Tags: java, maven, azure-pipelines

My unit tests for a Java app in Azure pipelines are failing even though they are fine when I build the same code elsewhere.   Failed unit tests are mostly java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError type of errors and inspection of the produced WAR file confirms that some dependencies are in fact missing.

I went as far as keeping everything the same and switching from Azure's build agents to a self hosted one.

Results:

- Self hosted: success
- Azure agent: failure

Here are the parts of the tool-chain that I verified are identical:

- Java version (pulling in specific JDK using JavaToolInstaller@0)
- Maven version (made sure to install identical mvn version on self hosted agent as Azure)
- Same pipeline except for build agent
- Source code (building the same commit)
- Same Linux 64bit architecture
- blew away $AGENT_USER_HOME\.m2 directory to make sure there was nothing funny left over

I'm checking these versions from the pipeline itself (by echoing vars).  And when I say identical, I mean that down to build number not just similar version.  The only thing that is slightly different is version displayed by uname: 5.13.0-1025-azure vs 5.REDACTED-generic, but that should not make any difference

What am I missing that could make a difference?  I thought that if I have the same java,pom,m2 and mvn, I'm guaranteed identical WAR.  It should even have the same hash or not?

What am I missing that's creating the difference?

Thank you

Comment: What is missing? What dependencies are marked as provided? Etc. I doubt anyone will be able to help too much without any specifics.

Comment: pom.xml had some dependencies marked at provided.  After your comment I removed the "provided" attribute and it didn't help.   Thinking about it some more, it makes sense that it didn't make a difference.  Because if that's what was broken, it would have failed on the self-hosted agent as well.  This question is more general than "why doesn't it work", I'm asking what could possibly cause the environments to behave differently if they are apparently identical.   In the end it's a question of build reproducibility (or at least near-reproducibility)

Comment: In theory env1(code + pom) = env2(code + pom) but mine are not equal. That must mean that it's env1(code + pom + x) = env2(code + pom + x).   I'm asking what x is.  Forget about my specific issue, what are the ingredients that make up a reproducible build?

Comment: Which scopes do you use?

Comment: Have you defined all versions of all plugins in your build...also not using any kind of version range... without the pom files it's hard to tell... Do you have dependencies which are architecture dependent? Also using the same Maven version? (mvn --version output ?)

Comment: I would take the build output of Maven and make a diff. @khmarbaise's guess is plausible.

Comment: That would be the first to do so... compare the log output of both builds... to have at least a starting point...

Comment: As per @JFabianMeier suggestion, I'm comparing the diff.  It's slow going because lot of the same dependencies are showing up in different order, so it's confusing the diff algorithm. In the end I think this is the way to untangle it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments, they helped me figure it out.   For some reason I needed to bring in a very specific .m2 folder from the other system for things to succeed.  I'm guessing this is related to "compile" vs "runtime".   Still trying to figure that out, but at least things make sense now.